# Programmatically changing portlet position in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop

I am using the ExtJS portal panels example for its drag and drop features. I have customized it to my needs but the general drag features and the drop zones are exactly like configured in the example. The next step we have to achieve is saving the state of the page i.e. the portlets need to be loaded in the correct column and order.

I have figured out how to save the data required in our database but my problem is that I do not know how to apply this "state". The portlets right now get loaded according to some configurations that come from an Ajax request to the DB. However the DB itself does not contain data about which column or what order the portlets are since this is saved from our state provider in a different table. When the state is loaded, I can decode the data about which column and what order the portlets should appear but that doesn't help since I cannot move them accordingly. I can't for example say: `Move portlet 1 to column 3 row 2`. Is there a way to achieve this?

What I'm looking for is something similar to:

```
updatePortletPos: function(portlet, position) {
  portlet.setColumn(position.x);
  portlet.setRow(position.y);
}
```

After this is called the portlet should change its position as if it was dragged to column 3 right under the first portlet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I have exactly 3 Columns with widgets. For each column I save an Array with the widget names and on load restore the sequence. The data is saved in the state provider (in my case into browser local storage).

Saving the state when a widget is moved:

```
Ext.define('Example.PortalPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    // ...
    getState: function () {
        var state = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var columnItems = this.items.getAt(i).items;
            state["column" + i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < columnItems.length; j++) {
                state["column" + i].push(columnItems.getAt(j).stateId);
            }
        }

        return state;
    }
}
```

And here the restoring the widgets from the state values:

```
Ext.define('Example.PortletPanel', {
    extend: 'Example.PortalPanel',
    initComponent: function () {
        //...
        var state = Ext.state.Manager.getProvider().get(this.getStateId());

        Ext.apply(this, {
            // ...
            items: [
                {
                    // column 1
                    items: []
                },
                {
                    // column 2
                    items: []
                },
                {
                    // column 3
                    items: []
                }
            ]
        });
        // insert the widgets to the columns according to their order in the state provider
        if (state) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var column = state["column" + i];
                if (column) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < column.length; j++) {
                        this.items[i].items.push(this.findWidgetByName(widgets, column[j]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    /**
     * Finds and returns a widget by name from an array with widgets
     */
    findWidgetByName: function (widgets, name) {
        //  ... 
    },
    /**
     * Create a widget instance according to the type ot the widget
     * @returns {Array}
     */
    generateWidgets: function () {
        //  ... my widgets are generated on the fly, receiving configuration and the data from server according to the current logged in user
    }
}
```

I think this is not the best solution, but it works.